# For each in by reference or value

Tags: foreach, scope, asp-classic

I have the following code:

```
dim key
for each key in Request.Querystring
  'do something
  key = sanitized_param(key)
next
```

My question for you classic-asp connoisseur, does classic-asp, or asp in general, pass the variables as references(memory), or by value? Trying to figure out if I sanitize the key variable and pass it back to itself, is it just "alive" for that loop, or does the new value get passed to the original QueryString?

Comment: `Request.QueryString` is a special type of **read-only** collection, others include `Request.Form` and `Request.ServerVariables`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Request.QueryString` retrieves the query string parameters by value from the page headers.

You can only make changes to a query string once its been retrieved via `Request.QueryString`, but you can't make changes directly to `Request.QueryString` as it's read-only (If you could make changes you would presumably use `Response.QueryString`, but this isn't a valid response command).

I'm guessing you're trying to sanitize all your query strings in one go? This isn't really possible or indeed necessary. You would typically sanitize a query string as and when you request it:

```vb
Response.Write(sanitized_param(Request.QueryString("myQS")))
```

Or to assign the query string to a variable first then sanitize it:

```vb
Dim myQS

myQS = Request.QueryString("myQS")
myQS = sanitized_param(myQS)

' or

myQS = sanitized_param(Request.QueryString("myQS"))
```

Once the query string has been assigned to a variable and sanitized you're able to reference that variable as often as you like without having to pass it to your sanitize function again.

Also, your example code doesn't make much sense. The `key` value in your `for each` loop is referencing just the names of your query strings and not their values. If `Response.QueryString` was a valid ASP command you would do:

`Response.QueryString(key) = sanitized_param(Request.QueryString(key))`

But again, this isn't possible.

---

**EDIT:** This solution might be what you're looking for:

Create a dictionary object, call it "QueryString" for example. Loop through all your query strings and add a sanitized version to the dictionary object.

```vb
Dim QueryString : Set QueryString = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each Item In Request.QueryString
    QueryString.Add Item,sanitized_param(Request.QueryString(Item))
next
```

Now, to retrieve a sanitized version of a query string just use:

```vb
QueryString.Item("query_string_name")
```

Or for the original unsanitized version you could still use:

```vb
Request.QueryString("query_string_name")
```

Just like `Request.QueryString`, the dictionary object is forgiving and won't return an error if you ask for a query string that doesn't exist.

---

You could also create a function for retrieving sanitized query strings, for example:

```vb
Function SanitizedQS(ByVal qsName)
    SanitizedQS = sanitized_param(Request.QueryString(qsName))
End Function
```

And rather than using `Request.QueryString("query_string_name")` just use `SanitizedQS("query_string_name")`.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, consider my code pseudo code, im aware of its improper syntax. But yest that is exactly what I am trying to do which is to sanitize all input queries in one go. I'll have to come up with a different solution, thanks.

Comment: @Irving Luna It is possible. You could loop through your query strings and add a sanitized version to a dictionary object, then just use the dictionary to retrieve sanitized query strings rather than using `Request.QueryString`. I've updated my answer with an example.